# Como colocar um java script dentro do value html

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma variável qualquer:

```
let variavel = x;
```

e tenho o input:

```
<input type="text" value="">
```

Existe uma forma em javascript puro de pegar uma variável ou um código javascript qualquer e colocar entro de tags html?

Neste exemplo ficaria assim:

```
<input type="text" value="<script>variavel</script>">
```

Sei que não é assim que funciona, mas tem uma forma semelhante a essa de se fazer isso com javascript? Obrigado a quem responder

Comment: isso abre uma porta gigante para XSS attacks, não ?

Comment: Nem conheço...rs

Comment: [Veja aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Talvez se voce explicar pra que voce quer fazer isso, poderia dar uma resposta adequada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina um id para seu elemento html

```
<input type="text" id="idUnico">
<script>
    var variavel = x;
    document.getElementById("idUnico").value = variavel;
</script>
```

Caso esteja usando jquery

```
<script>
    var variavel = x;
    $("#idUnico").val(variavel);
</script>
```

Comment: mas isso não está "colocando javascript" dentro do `input` como foi perguntado, mas apenas o valor da variável

Comment: Resposta candidata a receber -1.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta do Marcos:

Para você atribuir o valor, você usará:

`document.getElementById("idUnico").value = '<script>alert()</script>'`

Já para ler o valor, você usará:

`document.getElementById("idUnico").value`

Caso seja uma função dentro do value, eu acredito que você precisará pegá-la e injeta-la no HTML para que se torne disponível.

Se sua finalidade for fazer XSS, seja mais específico para que possamos responder de forma mais eficaz.

Eu creio que isso não seja uma boa pratica e pode dificultar a manutenção da sua aplicação.

Espero ter ajudado, mas acredito que possa haver uma forma mais coesa para resolver seu problema, talvez explicar o contexto nos ajude a te ajudar.

EDIT1: O conteúdo da variável é uma string, se tiver problemas com o uso do  basta passar apenas a função ou escapar os caracteres. Perceba que o value armazena uma string, não a função do JS. Um exemplo disso, é que você poderia muito bem converter sua função para base64 e salvar na variável. Na sequência, pegar a string e fazer o decode para ter a função limpa.